# $(0)$ is prime ideal in $M_n(D)$

Tags: ring-theory

I am not able to give an elementary proof of the fact that **the zero ideal is prime ideal in the matrix ring $M_n(D)$ over a division ring $D$**. Any hint?

In non-commutative ring $R$, a $2$-sided ideal $P$ is prime if $IJ\subseteq P$ implies $I\subseteq P$ or $J\subseteq P$ where $I,J$ are left (or right) ideals.

[by correspondence between $2$-sided ideals in $M_n(D)$ and $2$-sided ideals in $D$, the statement follows; but, can we prove it using definition of prime idesl?]

Comment: Can the product of two non zero ideals be zero?

Comment: Here the elements are matrices; I am not able to give precise reason.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I make a stupid mistake, the following works:

Assume $IJ=0$ and $I \neq 0, J \neq 0$.

Pick $A \in I$ non-zero. By multiplying to the left and right by permutation matrices you get a matrix in $I$ which has the 1,1 entry non-zero.

Next, multiply to the left and right by $E_{1,1}$, where $E_{1,1}$ is the matrix with 1 in the (1,1) position and zero everywhere else.

Do the same for $B$. This way you get some matrices $A' \in I, B' \in J$ with $A'B'$ being non-zero in position (1,1). Contradcition.

Comment: Very good. This is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that $R=M_n(D)$ has only trivial ideals?

There's exactly one case where both ideals are nonzero, hence $R$, and obviously $R^2\nsubseteq \{0\}$. In all other cases, one of the ideals is obviously $\{0\}$, hence contained in $\{0\}$.